# Typescript Modules: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import when importing module

Tags: typescript, module, ecmascript-6

Setup:

- VisualStudio 2017
- asp.net MVC app
- Typescript: ECMAScript 6, Module System: ES 2015 (don't mind
  changing those two, if my existing code    will still work)

Problem:

I've created many modules in my project. There are also nested modules and everything seems to work. But when starting my app, the console shows: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import**

So it doesn't know the **import** statement in my index.ts file (which is not a module!)

index.ts:

```
import { MyModule} from "./Modules/MyModule";

$().ready(function ()
{
   // some code
});
```

I've tried many things (changing Module System, ECMAScript version, etc.) and i cannot get it work. Without the import statement my code works, but I want to use TS modules. Any solutions?

Comment: How are you building your `*.ts` files? And how are the `*.js` files referenced in the HTML?

Comment: the .ts-files are built by Visual Studio when building the MVC app. The .js-file is referenced as .js in my site.cshtml

Comment: Are you importing `MyModule`(means from relative path `./Modules/MyModule`) correctly? Can you show us your project structure?

Comment: @slide_tackle You are likely generating the files targeting `es6` and running it in an environment that does not support ES6.

Comment: @Abraham Gnanasingh: The path is correct. Otherwise the  intellisense would show an error. The poblem definitly lies in the **import** statement

Comment: @Saravana: How can i determine my evironment does? What is a solution?

Comment: @slide_tackle Set the `target` to `es5` or lower in your `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: @Saravana doesn't help. As i have no tsconfig.json in my MVC app(only solution properties), is there anything else in this file which might is missed by Visual Studio?

Comment: @slide_tackle Were you ever able to figure this out? I tried messing with the solution properties setting ecma version to 5 and tried each of the module systems to no avail.

Comment: Actually I just stopped debugging, changed my solution properties so they used ECMAScript 6 (also tried ECMAScript 5) and CommonJS as the module system and then I ran debug again, now I am getting a new error in the console that reads: `require is not defined`

Comment: you need to use a module loader system to use modules like they are intended. For example you can use require.js. For some (i think) stupid reason this does not work with VS out of the box. I ended up not using modules like they should be used and import the generated js-files myself with a script tag.

Comment: @slide_tackle Yea I ended up doing that as well